# how to put font awesome icon in js toggle

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

Hi i have code like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    var elem = $("#toggle").text();
    if (elem == "Show more") {
      $("#toggle").text("Show less");
      $("#text").slideDown();
    } else {
      $("#toggle").text("Show more");
      $("#text").slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-container">
  <button id="toggle">Show more</button>
</div>
```

In show more i would like to add a icon /f078 and in show less /f106.
How to add? I tried by css and html tags but it doesnt work.

Comment: you can check font-awesome on how to get started. Basically you add classes. https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started

Comment: it sounds easy but it dont. i added a icon by content in css: 
#toggle:after {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
   content: "\f078";
   padding-left: 3px;
   font-weight: 900;
}

but i dont know how to rotate this icon (content only) on active toggle

Comment: could you update your question with that implementation (font awesome) and that code? There are a few ways you could rotate elements, it's easier to do when you see what you got to work with.